# Is it possible to set up anonymous chatter free users?

Tags: chatter, chatter-groups

We need to set up a private Chatter group but the people in this group can't know the identity of the other members. We thought we would give them avatar customer names but he/she would still have the ability to change their name and reveal their identity?

Comment: Perhaps you could write a validation rule on users that only allows a particular name? Or write a trigger to force a specific name? I'm not sure, but it seems something should be possible.